# Thickbox module not loading all images

Tags: 7

I just started using the ThickBox module to to create a simple gallery.  However, only some of the photos will load.  A couple will work, than one will just give the loading line and freeze on it.  I have the image module working fine and image caching as well.  Any idea what might be going on?  Thank you.

Comment: You can see it in this example http://hollywoodnose.com/category/image-galleries/jessica-alba-pics.  You'll notice that the first three images work and the last three don't.  P.S.  Sorry if the pics are a little riskay lol.  95% of the site isn't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) -- nothing to do with Drupal -- is no longer supported. I highly recomend using [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). ([On Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox))

(edit) The problem doesn't have anything to do with a modal image viewer. I inspected the code to find the URL of each image and they don't work. Chances are that the images are not being uploaded complete because of an upload limit or they are too large for image cache to successfully manipulate.

In php.ini make sure that:

```
max_execution_time to around 120 and
realpath_cache_size to 512K, 1M or even 2M.
max_input_time to around 120.
post_max_size = 12M to 16M (or large enough for your images)
upload_max_filesize = 12M to 16M (or large enough for your images)
```

In the content type widget configuration make sure that Upload Max size is set accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, I just activated colorbox and it looks great.  However, I'm having the same problem.  The exact same think is happening that happened with thickbox.  I've tried it with multiple galleries.  Some pictures load and others don't.  Is this common?  Thank you again.

Comment: It's quite likely you have a permissions problem in the files directory. You should probably make sure that the owner of everything in there is your webserver user and that the permissions are set correctly. It may very well be imagecache that's your problem - it's unable to create the pictures you're requesting.

Comment: Images are stored in sites/default/files/images and I tried setting file permissions "all on" for the "images" folder and the individual images that aren't loading.  Also, I have image cache along with all of its submodules enabled an all file permissions on.  Is it possible that the owner of the image can do this sort of thing if it's not a General Public License?  Cause I feel like I've got everything running correctly.  Yet, only some of the images are working.  Is this sort of thing common?  Thank you again for your input on this matter.

Comment: Got it (kind of)!  Great advice and thank you so much for bearing with me through that.  Ironically the problem was the preview function in the colorbox Image derivative settings were acting funky.  I set it to display original image instead of preview and it worked.  Weird... It had to of been something with the resizing/cropping of the images etc.  Cause the the pictures that weren't working had "more" and "less" kb associated to the file.  Weird one.  Thanks again!